# Is every recursive algorithm a divide and conquer algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I have a problem for homework and I need to solve this problem with a divide and conquer algorithm.

I solved this algorithm by using recursion. Did I use divide and conquer automatically by using recursion?

For example, is this below approach a divide an conquer algorithm? Because I use `fun` function in `fun`.(recursive call)

Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

/* int a[] = {-6,60,-10,20}; */
int a[] =  {-2, -3, 4, -1, -2, 1, 5, -3};
int len = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);
int maxherearray[10];

int fun(int n);
int max(int a, int b);
int find_max(int a[], int len);
void print_array(int a[], int start_idx, int end_idx);

int start_idx = 0;  // Start of contiguous subarray giving max sum
int end_idx = 0;    // End of contiguous subarray giving max sum

#define NEG_INF (-100000)

int max_sum = NEG_INF;  // The max cont sum seen so far.

int main(void)
{
    start_idx = 0;
    end_idx = len - 1;
    maxherearray[0] = a[0];

    printf("Array a[]: ");
    print_array(a, 0, len-1);
    printf("\n");

    // Compute the necessary information to get max contiguous subarray
    fun(len - 1);
    printf("Max subarray value == %d\n", find_max(maxherearray, len));
    printf("\n");

    printf("Contiguous sums: ");
    print_array(maxherearray, 0, len - 1);
    printf("\n");

    printf("Contiguous subarray giving max sum: ");
    print_array(a, start_idx, end_idx);
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}

int fun(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return a[0];

    int max_till_j = fun(n - 1);

    // Start of new contiguous sum
    if (a[n] > a[n] + max_till_j)
    {
        maxherearray[n] = a[n];

        if (maxherearray[n] > max_sum)
        {
            start_idx = end_idx = n;
            max_sum = maxherearray[n];
        }
    }
    // Add to current contiguous sum
    else
    {
        maxherearray[n] = a[n] + max_till_j;

        if (maxherearray[n] > max_sum)
        {
            end_idx = n;
            max_sum = maxherearray[n];
        }
    }

    return maxherearray[n];
}

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b)? a : b;
}

// Print subarray a[i] to a[j], inclusive of end points.
void print_array(int a[], int i, int j)
{
    for (; i <= j; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}

int find_max(int a[], int len)
{
    int i;
    int max_val = NEG_INF;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] > max_val)
        {
            max_val = a[i];
        }
    }

    return max_val;
}
```

Comment: No, not necessarily. Whe might be able to answer, if you explain the problem and the algorithm.

Comment: @Henry, I edited the post,could you please look that the problem?

Comment: When you divide the original problem into 2 smaller problem, solve them & combine the results, that's divide & conquer.

Comment: According to Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm#Divide_and_conquer this is completely opinion-based question as "The name 'divide and conquer' is sometimes applied to algorithms that reduce each problem to only one sub-problem," - so you need to clarify what definition is used by your school. Otherwise just argue that "I divided problem into two parts {n} {0,...n-1} and inlined trivial case for {n} - so this is *clearly* divide and conquer" :)

Comment: binary search can be recursive, and is not a "divide and conquer" by any definition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every recursion function is not necessarily divide-and-conquer approach. There are other approaches like decrease-and-conquer(*decrease by a constant factor*, *decrease by one*, *variable-size decrease*).

> Is this below approach a divide an conquer algorithm?

Your function is exactly decrease by a constant factor which is `1` approach. You can glance at [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190408192806/http://faculty.simpson.edu/lydia.sinapova/www/cmsc250/LN250_Levitin/L07-DecreaseConquer.htm).

Pseudocode for the divide-and-conquer algorithm for
finding a maximum-subarray

```
MaxSubarray(A,low,high)
//
if high == low   
   return (low, high, A[low]) // base case: only one element
else
   // divide and conquer
   mid = floor( (low + high)/2 )
   (leftlow,lefthigh,leftsum) = MaxSubarray(A,low,mid)
   (rightlow,righthigh,rightsum) = MaxSubarray(A,mid+1,high)
   (xlow,xhigh,xsum) = MaxXingSubarray(A,low,mid,high)
   // combine
   if leftsum >= rightsum and leftsum >= xsum
      return (leftlow,lefthigh,leftsum)
   else if rightsum >= leftsum and rightsum >= xsum
      return (rightlow,righthigh,rightsum)
   else
      return (xlow,xhigh,xsum)
   end if
end if

--------------------------------------------------------------

MaxXingSubarray(A,low,mid,high)
// Find a max-subarray of A[i..mid]
leftsum = -infty
sum = 0
for i = mid downto low
    sum = sum + A[i]
    if sum > leftsum
       leftsum = sum
       maxleft = i
    end if
end for
// Find a max-subarray of A[mid+1..j]
rightsum = -infty
sum = 0
for j = mid+1 to high
    sum = sum + A[j]
    if sum > rightsum
       rightsum = sum
       maxright = j
    end if
end for
// Return the indices i and j and the sum of the two subarrays
return (maxleft,maxright,leftsum + rightsum)

-----------------------------------------------------------

=== Remarks:

(1) Initial call: MaxSubarray(A,1,n)

(2) Divide by computing mid.
    Conquer by the two recursive alls to MaxSubarray.
    Combine by calling MaxXingSubarray and then determining
       which of the three results gives the maximum sum.

(3) Base case is when the subarray has only 1 element.
```

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily. If you explore the functional programming paradigm you will learn that the simple `for` loop can be replaced with recursion

```
for i in range(x):
    body(i)
```

changes to

```
def do_loop(x, _start=0):
    if _start < x:
         body(_start)
         do_loop(x, _start=_start+1)
```

and it's quite obvious that not every iteration is a divide and conquer algorithm.

Comment: In my edited post, Is it divide and conquer algorithm?